# Chrome shows only up to 50 rows of indexeddb table data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb

I am experimenting with indexeddb, and have some data added to ObjectStore which should have 90 rows.

But I can see only 50 rows in Chrome development tools.

Is it Chrome that limits the rows, or my code is not adding more than 50 rows?
For example:

```
for (var i=0; i< 100; i++){
    var tmp = "data" + i;
    store.put({question: tmp});
}
```

this code adds only 50 rows/data into store even though I am adding 100.

Thanks forward

Comment: Yes, it seems like chrome is showing only 50 items. I can search with key using chrome search, and it shows correctly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic

Comment: Hi, consider making the answer below accepted.

Comment: Thanks for reminding. I do not know why I did not accept it before.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can navigate through all items in the Chrome resource tab using the navigation controls on top of the screen. Please see the attached picture:

[image: Chrome resource tab]

Comment: in 2022 this pointed out I was chasing my tail with a non existent bug for the past few hours!