# Firefox, can only see 50 rows of indexeddb data

Tags: firefox, indexeddb

I've tried my best to research this and I've found this answer here for Chrome:

[Chrome shows only up to 50 rows of indexeddb table data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355566/chrome-shows-only-up-to-50-rows-of-indexeddb-table-data)

But in firefox I can't find any errors, I can only see 50 rows of data and can't see any option to view the rest, I know there is more there though! Does anyone know how to scroll through the rest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug:

> The actor protocol supports a start index and each query is defaulted to return at max 50 items, unless asked otherwise.
>
> Thus this is only a UI limitation i.e. there exists no UI to request next set of items. Alternatively, there is no UI to get X number of items from the actor.

**References**

- [LocalStorage inspector does not show all key-value pairs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1171903)

Comment: So, no solution for this yet? this bug is more than 2 years old

Comment: I'm currently working on a project which is kinda robust, Advance PWA. I'm seriously in need of this feature, Currently i'm using cursor and pagination to extend records. people actually think their data was not complete.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug [1434579](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1434579): 
Devtools IndexedDB object store view shows max 50 objects 
RESOLVED FIXED in **Firefox 63**